# GridVIew: Toggle edit and update button when editing

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I want a GridView with visible "Edit" button and hidden "Update" button and when enetring edit mode for a row toggle visibility, like [this example in here](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/tutorials/controls/gridview.aspx) (around the middle of the page, I think he does with  AutoGenerateEditButton="true").

This are my grid buttons:

```
    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="campoCentrado">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="btEditarGrid" ImageUrl="~/imagenes/edit.png" CommandName="Edit" OnClick="GridView_EditMode" runat="server" />
            <asp:ImageButton ID="btGuardarGrid" ImageUrl="~/imagenes/guardar.png" CommandName="Update" Visible="false" runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="btInsertarGrid" ImageUrl="~/imagenes/insertar.png" OnClick="GridView_Insert" runat="server" />
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

And my RowEditingevent, which doesn't work:

```
Private Sub gvCuestionarios_RowEditing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewEditEventArgs) Handles gvCuestionarios.RowEditing
    If e.NewEditIndex >= 0 Then
        Dim guardar As ImageButton = gvCuestionarios.Rows(e.NewEditIndex).FindControl("btGuardarGrid")
        If Not guardar Is Nothing Then
            guardar.Visible = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Thank you

Comment: means row Editing event is not firing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your TemplateField add an EditItemTemplate and place your update button inside of it. Once you're in edit mode it doesn't matter if you make a button visible or not in the ItemTemplate, it won't be displayed. This is because you are in the EditItemTemplate and not the ItemTemplate.

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="campoCentrado">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="btEditarGrid" ImageUrl="~/imagenes/edit.png" CommandName="Edit" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="btUpdateGrid" ImageUrl="~/imagenes/guardar.png" CommandName="Update" runat="server" />
        <!-- This would be to cancel out of Edit mode, would need to have a cancel.png -->
        <asp:ImageButton ID="btGuardarGrid" ImageUrl="~/imagenes/cancel.png" CommandName="Cancel" runat="server" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="btInsertarGrid" ImageUrl="~/imagenes/insertar.png" OnClick="GridView_Insert" runat="server" />
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add an Edit button as an ImageButton, the easiest way would be to use the CommandField:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCuestionarios" runat="server" 
    OnRowCancelingEdit="gvCuestionarios_RowCancelingEdit"
    OnRowEditing="gvCuestionarios_RowEditing" 
    OnRowUpdating="gvCuestionarios_RowUpdating">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField 
            ShowEditButton="true"
            ShowCancelButton="true"
            ButtonType="Image" 
            EditImageUrl="~/imagenes/edit.png"
            UpdateImageUrl="~/imagenes/guardar.png"
            CancelImageUrl="~/imagenes/cancel.png" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Note that I have added a cancel button with cancel.png as the image that will appear when the grid goes into edit mode.

In the RowEditing event you now don't have to worry about manually hiding or displaying the buttons, you just set the EditIndex and rebind your data:

```
Private Sub gvCuestionarios_RowEditing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewEditEventArgs) Handles gvCuestionarios.RowEditing
    gvCuestionarios.EditIndex = -1
    BindData()
End Sub
```

The only problem that this might cause is that you won't be able to have a custom footer template on that column. There is likely a better way to do what you are trying to accomplish with that footer anyways.

Comment: Actually both solutions seem good to me, I choose he first one as it's more similar to my start point but will try this one also, thank you